# Can you store and retrieve apk file from Firebase?

Tags: file, firebase, apk

i've seen a lot of tutorial on uploading and retrieving images to and from Firebase. Does it also work on an apk file or a 3d model (.fbx,.obj)?

Comment: So want to send apk file to firebase and want to fetch when needed . right ?

Comment: yup, something like that. I was thinking of uploading an apk file (eg: Unity game) to Firebase and if there's any changes, i'd just edit the code from Unity, then download it. Was wondering if its possible or does it require some complex steps?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can store any kind of binary data in Cloud Storage - images are just one of the most common use cases.

Comment: does it require a new set of steps or do you have to replace the image address with the .obj address?

Comment: So, when it stores a file, can the user download the file to their device without developing any android app? I've seen many tutorials to upload and download images to/from firebase. I wonder if it can be done without an app from android studio, like a google drive?